# Jackson parse Integer to Double

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Environment: `JACKSON 2.8.10` with `Spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE`

In a JSON request I receive the following:

```
{
  total: 103
}
```

In other cases the `total` might be with decimal precision for example: `103.25`. I would like to be able to handle both cases using `JACKSON`

In my Java, I would like to read this 103 into a `double` as such:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
                .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider()).build();
Object rawJson = conf.jsonProvider().parse(payload);
double listPrice = JsonPath.read(rawJson, "$.total")
```

But then I receive the following error:

```
Java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double.
```

Is there a way to handle the case above without doing string/mathematical manipulations?

Comment: You can define your `payload` as a class and let the `total` be a `Double`

Comment: @dashboard I can't do that. It involves way too much refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to handle the case above without doing string/mathematical manipulations?

This should do it.

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder()
       .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
       .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
       .build();
Object rawJson = conf.jsonProvider().parse(payload);
Object rawListPrice = JsonPath.read(rawJson, "$.total");
double listPrice;
if (rawListPrice instanceOf Double) {
    listPrice = (Double) rawListPrice;
} else if (rawListPrice instanceOf Integer) {
    listPrice = (Integer) rawListPrice;
} else {
    throw new MyRuntimeException("unexpected type: " + rawListPrice.getClass());
}
```

If you are going to do this repeatedly, create a method ...

```
public double toDouble(Object number) {
    if (number instanceof Double) {
        return (Double) number;
    } else if (number instanceof Integer) {
        return (Integer) number;
    } else {
        throw new MyRuntimeException("unexpected type: " + number.getClass());
    }
}
```

---

The root cause of the exception is that the return type of `JsonPath.read` is an unconstrained type parameter.  The compiler infers it to be whatever the call site expects, and adds a hidden typecast to ensure that the actual value returned has the expected type.

The problem arises when the `JsonPath.read` could actually return multiple types in a single call.  The compiler has no way of knowing what *could* be returned ... or how to convert it.

Solution: take care of the conversion with some runtime type checking.

---

Here is another solution that should work:

```
double listPrice = ((Number) JsonPath.read(rawJson, "$.total")).doubleValue();
```

... modulo that you will still get an `ClassCastException` if the value for "total" in the JSON is (say) a String.